# Techniques for categorising natural language strings?

Tags: java, python, ruby, nlp

What is available in terms of libraries / open-source software for processing and categorising natural language? I've got a database full of strings which are user descriptions of a particular item. I'd like to categorise these words to weed out the useless and make an educated guess as to what category the item fits into (e.g Technology, Sport, Music).

I realise this a fairly specific request and my knowledge of natural language processing is very limited. I'm wondering what would be the best and if possible most computationally cheap way of making these sort of predictions?

I would prefer to do this in Ruby however, Python or Java is also acceptable.

Comment: Hmm, this sounds like something I saw on MTurk a while back. Related?

Comment: I had to Google MTurk to find out what that was. So I think thats a no :)

Comment: I have very fine Perl answers for you, but apparently you don't want to hear about those.  Oh well.

Comment: List of natural language processing toolkits at wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_natural_language_processing_toolkits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to Python, for the moment I can recommend looking into:

http://www.nltk.org/

It has good documentation, and lots of lots of functionality in the field of natural language processing. Also there is a package in the Ubuntu repository (python-nltk), so it's easy to install and experiment with.

For most situations you'll need access to a good quality corpus.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Ruby doesn't have a quality NLP, however if you use [JRuby](http://www.jruby.org/), you can take advantage of Java's quality NLP's such as:

[GATE](http://gate.ac.uk/)

[LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/)

[OpenNLP](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: +1. I wrote a prototype using JRuby and OpenNLP for work, it was quite a good experience.

Answer (score 1):

One of the top linguistic libraries for any programming language is called [Wordnet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/). It's used to parse text, break it down, and determine parts of speech. If you saw IBM's Watson compete on the TV show Jeopardy, you saw Wordnet in action as it was one of the technologies used.

There is a "[WordNet for Ruby](http://deveiate.org/projects/Ruby-WordNet)" gem. I haven't used it, but I've used Wordnet many times. Hopefully Wordnet's installation will have become easier as it was a pain in the past.

Perl has the [Lingua::Wordnet](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Lingua-Wordnet/Wordnet.pm) module that I have used. Also, a quick search for "Python + wordnet" returns several hits.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a bunch of text chunks that you want to classify into different categories. The problem is identical to spam filtering. Except a [spam filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering) only classifies emails into two categories, but you have several, but the same principles ([Bayes' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27s_theorem)) still applies. A [Naive Bayes classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) is one of the simplest and least computationally demanding methods to tackle the problem. Then you can build on that knowledge and use more complicated methods such as neural networks to make more accurate classifications. A great book on the topic is [Programming Collective Intelligence](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529321).

See also [dANN](http://wiki.syncleus.com/index.php/dANN%3aNaive_Classifier) which is a Java library that has a Naive Bayes classifier implementation and many other tools for predictive analysis. And this [video about Google Predict](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbkwv1wjs3A) which shows how to categorize sentences into languages. The same method could be used for classifying descriptions almost verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

Check this list of natural language processing toolkits http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_natural_language_processing_toolkits.
Some not mentioned here:
Weka, Mallet, Stanford Classifier